# Dealing with Device-Mapper (Multipath) Failing paths

Tags: linux, scsi, multipath-storage

When a disk starts to die slowly multipath starts to Failing & Reinstating paths and this keeps forever.. (I'm using LSI-3008HBA card with SAS-JBOD not FC-Network)

Dmesg;

```
Sep 13 11:20:17 DEV2 kernel: sd 0:0:190:0: attempting task abort! scmd(ffff88110e632948)
Sep 13 11:20:17 DEV2 kernel: sd 0:0:190:0: [sdft] tag#3 CDB: opcode=0x0 00 00 00 00 00 00
Sep 13 11:20:17 DEV2 kernel: scsi target0:0:190: handle(0x0037), sas_address(0x5000c50093d4e7c6), phy(38)
Sep 13 11:20:17 DEV2 kernel: scsi target0:0:190: enclosure_logical_id(0x500304800929ec7f), slot(37)
Sep 13 11:20:17 DEV2 kernel: scsi target0:0:190: enclosure level(0x0001),connector name(1   )
Sep 13 11:20:17 DEV2 kernel: sd 0:0:190:0: task abort: SUCCESS scmd(ffff88110e632948)
Sep 13 11:20:18 DEV2 kernel: device-mapper: multipath: Failing path 130:240.
Sep 13 11:25:34 DEV2 kernel: device-mapper: multipath: Reinstating path 130:240.
```

As you can see kernel aborted the mission and after that multipath failed.
So I want to get rid of this problem via telling Multipath "do not Reinstate the path".
This method will keep dead the zombie disk.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

We would need to know how multipath is determining a path is alive. If you look at [multipath.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/multipath.conf) you will see there's an optional path_checker `option` you can see a list of them (with the default being `readsector0`). Another thing to do is have a path priority ordering such that your path grouping such that disabling failback will prevent it being used unless there's an emergency. According to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/removing-path-to-storage-device after removing manual references to the `sdft` you could use the following (but substitute `sdft` for `sda` to match the case you gave):

> Take the path offline using `echo offline > /sys/block/sda/device/state`.
>
> This will cause any subsequent I/O sent to the device on this path to be failed immediately. **Device-mapper-multipath** will continue to use the remaining paths to the device.